# Visual Studio Form Designer Showing List of Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I know that getting the **Form Designer** to work is a ticklish business.  Generics, x64, subtle problems with the project's XML...  But perhaps someone can offer advice about my current problem, which is that a component I created that inherits from `TabPage`, when I try to view it in the designer shows up as a list of its controls, like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TabPage` inherits from `Panel` which eventually inherits from `Control`. Custom controls don't offer the designer view we are used to when designing a `Form` or `UserControl`. I'd suggest inheriting from `UserControl` and add it to the `.Controls` property of any `TabPage`. Although I'm not sure that this is what you are asking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a `TabPage` as root of the designer, while you can do the same for a `Panel` or other container controls. The limitation is because, `TabPage` can only be hosted in `TabControl`, not even in the overlay control of the designer:

> TabPage cannot be added to a
> 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.DesignerFrame+OverlayControl'.  TabPages
> can only be added to TabControls.

A control can be shown as root of the designer when the base class of the control has designer of type of [`DocumentDesigner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.documentdesigner?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). `Form` and `UserControl` are such controls which means when you create a new `Form1:Form` or new `UserControl1:UserControl`, since the base class derived from a designable control, then the class can be edited in the designer as root.

I believe you can handle your requirement by using `UserControl`, but for learning purpose (or as a workaround) if you want to make a control deriving from `Panel` designable, you can copy the following code in a code file:

```
public class MyControl: MyDesignableControl
{
}
[Designer(typeof(DocumentDesigner), typeof(IRootDesigner))]
public class MyDesignableControl : Panel
{

}
```

Then save it and then double click on it and you can see you can design it like a root control.

Then after you done with the design, change the `Panel` to `TabPage`.

> [Remarks on
> DocumentDesigner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.documentdesigner?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
>
> This designer is a root designer, meaning that it provides the
> root-level design mode view for the associated document when it is
> viewed in design mode.
>
> You can associate a designer with a type using a
> [`DesignerAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerattribute?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
> For an overview of customizing design time behavior, see [Extending
> Design-Time
> Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/37899azc(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).